# How could Klall Yisrael make a Bamah when the Mishkan was in Shilo (Acc. to Metzudos David)?

Tags: tanach, shoftim--book-of, bamot

The incident of the [Pelegesh B'Gibeah](http://www.sefaria.org/Judges.19?lang=bi) and its aftermath as described in the last few Perakim in Sefer Shoftim discusses that after Benei Yisrael annihilated all of Sheivet Binyamin except for 600 men who fled to [Selah Rimmon](http://www.sefaria.org/Judges.20.45?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

The [Metzudos David](http://www.sefaria.org/Judges.21.1?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=bi) points out that in the beginning of the [last perek](http://www.sefaria.org/Judges.21.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) of Sefer Shoftim that the oath that Klall Yisrael makes against Shevet Binyamin occurred before the massacre of the Shevet. The proceeding verse then states that Klall Yisrael regretted making that oath. In they're regret the verse states (21:2)

> וַיָּבֹ֤א הָעָם֙ בֵּֽית־אֵ֔ל וַיֵּ֤שְׁבוּ שָׁם֙ עַד־הָעֶ֔רֶב לִפְנֵ֖י הָאֱלֹהִ֑ים וַיִּשְׂא֣וּ קוֹלָ֔ם וַיִּבְכּ֖וּ בְּכִ֥י גָדֽוֹל׃
>
> *And the nation came to Beis El and they dwelled there until the evening before G-d and they raised their voices and they cried a great cry*

The [Metzudos David](http://www.sefaria.org/Judges.21?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_Judges.21.5&lang2=bi) comments on this verse (partial quote):

> בית אל . אל בית האלהים אשר בשילה
>
> *Bais El: The house of G-d which was in Shilo*

Two verses later in Sefer Shoftim it says (21:4)

> וַֽיְהִי֙ מִֽמָּחֳרָ֔ת וַיַּשְׁכִּ֣ימוּ הָעָ֔ם וַיִּבְנוּ־שָׁ֖ם מִזְבֵּ֑חַ וַיַּעֲל֥וּ עֹל֖וֹת וּשְׁלָמִֽים׃
>
> *And it was the next day the nation arose early and **they built there an altar** and they brought burnt-offerings and peace-offerings*

The Metzudos David comments:

> ויבנו שם מזבח . נוסף על המזבח שעמד במשכן
>
> *And they built there an Altar: Besides for the one that was standing in the Mishkan (in Shilo)*

**My Question**

In the Last Perek of [Meseches Zevachim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodashim#Zevachim) in ([14:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Zevachim.14?lang=bi)) the Mishna says (partial quote):

> באו לשילה נאסרו הבמות
>
> When (the Mishkan) was moved to Shilo, Bamos (personal altars) were prohibited (to bring sacrifices on)

How could it be that Klall Yisrael built an Altar and bring sacrifices outside of Mishkan Shilo to beseech mercy from H-Shem at a time where such practice was prohibited as described in the Mishna?